# Cache - Update em meu site

Tags: php, cache

Galera, alguém tem alguma explicação ou uma visão pra mim entender melhor sobre os cookies para ele ser atualizado.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um site em PHP/HTML. Na maioria das vezes sempre quando eu faço um update em alguma função ou CSS, eu preciso limpar o cache do meu navegador para poder ver o update.

Alguma solução viável ou uma ajuda possível?

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Na verdade você não limpa os *Cookies*, mas sim o *Cache*.

Comment: Isso! Me posicionei de forma errada. Obrigado por corrigir!

Answer (score -1):

Esse é o comportamento padrão dos navegadores, visando desempenho, como sabemos, eu já me acostumei com o `ctrl+shift+r` para limpar o cache, porém se você preferir e usar o chrome, eis uma solução:

**Pressione F12 -> Clique na guia *Network* -> Marque a opção *Disable cache*.**

Espero ter ajudado.